# Get notified about new window is being shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwindow, intercom

I have an issue: a third party messaging component (named [Intercom](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios)) is presenting a new UIWindow above the application's key window. I would like to get notified about when the it is happening, but no success. My attempts so far:

> KVO for the UIApplication's keywindow property
>
> KVO for the UIApplication's windows array
>
> KVO for the UIApplication's keyWindow's level
>
> view(Did/Will)Dissapear

Do you have any more ideas to solve it? thanks

Comment: I don't think you can get notified when a window of another app is presented.

Comment: If you are talking about your own app try `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` or `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification`.

Comment: It's almost good, but the notification is presented before the view is loaded, so I can't get any information about it :(